# Wordpress enque style sheet not loading in chrome

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-chrome

I have enqued my external stylesheet in `wordpress` theme. It is working fine in `firefox`, but not loading in Chrome.

```
function cliff_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'cliff-style-extended', 'http://imransaeed.info/wp-content/projects/cliff/style-extended.css', date('his'), true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cliff_scripts' );
```

this code I am using, but it loads my stylesheet into firefox but not found stylesheet in chrome source.

Comment: this function work on other websites perfect, only now I am facing this problem on a website.

Comment: date('his') ?? what this stands for in  wp_enqueue_style .. 3rd parameter must be for dependency parameter